# Put integer in to string using push_back

Tags: c++, string, integer

I am trying to put an integer in to string using the following code:

```
int x = 42;
string num;
bool negative = false;

if(x < 0)
{
   negative = true;
   x = x * -1;
}
while(x > 0)
{
  num.push_back(x % 10);
  x = x / 10;
}
```

But when I try to output the string, it comes up with the wired character. Could you please help what's happening in this code??

Edited:
ps. I want to do this in kind manual way. Means I don't want to use to_string

Comment: Note: your code won't do anything for `x == 0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There would be *weird* characters, because when you `push_back()`, the integer is **converted (or rather interpreted) into its corresponding ASCII character**, and then pushed back into the string.

The way forward is to convert the integer to a character by adding a `'0'` to the integer value.

```
while(x > 0)
{
  num.push_back((x % 10) + '0'); //Adding '0' converts the number into
                                 //its corresponding ASCII value.
  x = x / 10;
}
```

#### The reason to add a `'0'` to the integer?

The ASCII value of 0 is 48, 1 is 49, 2 is 50 and so on... Hence, what we basically do here is to add 48 (The ASCII value of 0) to the corresponding integer to make it equal to its ASCII equivalent. Incidentally, `'0'` is equal to 48 because it *is* the ASCII value of the `0` *character*.

Comment: Hi, thank you! This is working! Could you please explain the use of '0'? or any reference? thank you again~!

Comment: I'd rather say that the integer is *not* converted but that it is simply interpreted differently. For a proper conversion, I'd use `"0123456789"[x % 10]`. The use of `'0'` as base works because it is followed by the other digits in pretty much every charset.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Indeed. I just gave the OP the easiest way to accomplish this, without changing much of his code.

Comment: Won't this reverse the number? e.g. 13 ---> 3 and 1 so 31.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::to_string` with `string::append`:

```
while (x > 0)
{
    num.append(std::to_string(x % 10));
    x = x / 10;
}
```

using `push_back` forces you to do more work.

Comment: Yes you do, this loop doesn't do the same as `to_string()` does. Firstly, it skips zeros and secondly it results in a reversed numeric string.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the integer you can use:

1. Character manipulation: shifting/adding the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) representation by `'0'`, thereby making an`int` value into `char` value.
2. Type casting `new_type(old_type)`, there are some additional [types of casting](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/).

To expand the length of a string you can use:

1. String [member functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) like: `push_back(value)`, `append(append)`.
2. [Concatenation operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/) like: `str += value`;

A possible implementation is:

```
while(x > 0)
{
 num+=((x % 10) + '0');                             
 x = x / 10;
}
```